# Is this called an identity?

Tags: terminology

> Identity is an equation which is true regardless of what values are substituted for any variables (if there are any variables at all).

The question is:
$$\frac{x^2-a^2}{x-a}=x+a$$

Is this an identity?

This equation is not true if $x=a$.

And how it's called if not.

Comment: If $x = a$, then the left-hand side is undefined.

Comment: It's almost true. It's true for every value of $x$ except $x=a$.

Comment: It is not that the equation is not true if $x=a$. If $x=a$ then the equation simply does not make sense. Equations that do not make sense are neither true nor false —nor anything else, for that matter!

Comment: I suspect what you intended was $\dfrac{x^2-a^2}{x-a}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Sorry. Fixed this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I suspect there's a typo: I think it should be $$"{x^2-a^2\over x-a}=x+a."$$ (The "$x^2$" is an "$x$" in the OP.) E.g., set $x=2, a=1$ - in the OP this would yield 1=3.

Second, as the comments have pointed out, even with that fix, it's false if $x=a$.

---

There's an important conceptual issue lurking here: there are some functions, which are not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, but which "ought" to be in the sense that there is a natural function, extending the given function, which *is* defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. E.g., $f(x)={x^2-1\over x-1}$ agrees with $g(x)=x+1$ wherever the former is defined, and $g$ is defined everywhere; so in some sense we might think that $f$ actually *is* $g$. But it's not - even though $f$ can be naturally "completed," that would be a different function. The specific $f$ is not defined everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The term "identity" is vague without a specified domain. The above is not an identity for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ because it isn't true for $x = a$, but it is true for $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{a\}$ because, by the definition, the statement is true for all $x$ in the domain.

This answer takes into account the typo Emilio Novati noted.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your question is about
$$
\dfrac{x^2-a^2}{x-a}=x+a
$$

and this is an idenity for $x\ne a$  but is not an identity for $x=a$ because  the Left side is not defined.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?